# Como fazer meu programa consumir menos CPU sem atrapalhar sua execução?

Tags: c#, thread, desempenho

Tenho um programa que lê a memória de um processo do computador de forma contínua (com o `while (true)`), mas isso acaba exigindo muita CPU, chegando em 20% usado, minha pergunta é, como diminuir o uso da CPU sem perder desempenho no programa?

Tentei o `Thread.Sleep(10)`, funcionou, o uso da CPU abaixou para 1%, mas mesmo sendo somente 10 milésimos, o desempenho do programa caiu drasticamente.

```
while (Vars.GlowActive) //Essa variavel sempre vai ser true
    if (Vars.GlowAlways || Vars.GetKeyState(Vars.GlowButton) == 0)
    {
        for (int num = 1; num < 24; num++)
        {
            int entity = mem.Read<int>(Vars.bClient + Vars.EntList + (num * 0x10));
            ehealth = mem.Read<int>(entity + Vars.Health);

            int Glow = mem.Read<int>(entity + Vars.GlowIndex);
            int EntTeam = mem.Read<int>(entity + Vars.Team);
            if (EntTeam == Vars.MyTeam)
            {
                if (Vars.glowteamenabled)
                {
                    if (Vars.TeamRainbow)
                        TeamColor();
                    color[0] = Vars.glow_team_r / 255;
                    color[1] = Vars.glow_team_g / 255;
                    color[2] = Vars.glow_team_b / 255;
                    DrawGlow(Glow, color);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Vars.glowenemyenabled)
                {
                    if (Vars.EnemyRainbow)
                        EnemyColor();
                    else if (Vars.glowhealth)
                    {
                        Vars.glow_enemy_r = 255 - 2.55f * ehealth;
                        Vars.glow_enemy_g = 2.55f * ehealth;
                        Vars.glow_enemy_b = 0;
                    }
                    color[0] = Vars.glow_enemy_r / 255;
                    color[1] = Vars.glow_enemy_g / 255;
                    color[2] = Vars.glow_enemy_b / 255;
                    DrawGlow(Glow, color);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (one && Vars.BeepEnable)
    {
        Console.Beep(3000, 200);
        one = !one;
    }
}
```

Sumario:

`mem.Read` lê a memoria de um processo.

`DrawGlow()` escreve na memória.

Comment: Ao invés de while não poderia usar uma rotina de evento? Ou até um timer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx não entendo muito de C#, de qualquer forma creio que não era para cair o desempenho ao usar `Thread.Sleep`, pode ser algum "conflito".

Comment: Como funciona uma rotina de eventos? Nunca ouvir falar na tal...

Comment: talvez eu não tenha escolhido as melhores palavras, por exemplo usar o OnTimedEvent para ficar executando em paralelo. Ainda sim creio que não era para ter caido o desempenho só por causa de um Sleep. Esse `Thread` pode estar sendo executado multiplas vezes? Ou algo assim? Talvez seja possivel resolver no teu código e o problema nem sequer seja o Sleep.

Comment: Não, ele é executado uma unica vez, porem ele está dentro de um while true. Vou colocar o código na pergunta.

Comment: Você resolveu com o `System.Timers.Timer`? Quase acertei xD

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim, foi por pouco. =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimente diminuir a duração do sleep

```
Thread.Sleep(1);
```

Ou use um [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var timer =  new  System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Interval = 10;
timer.Elapsed += (ctx, arg) => /*chama a sua funcao aqui*/;
timer.AutoReset = true;
timer.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

### Nem tudo, nem nada

Um programa que executa sem parar consome mais CPU. Um programa que dorme sempre perde desempenho. Que tal então fazer as duas coisas, mas não sempre?

```
        while ( Vars.GlowActive )
        {
            if ( Vars.GlowAlways || Vars.GetKeyState( Vars.GlowButton ) == 0 )
            {
                for ( int num = 1 ; num < 24 ; num++ ) // Ver observação
                {
                }

                // Já que teve uma execuçao válida, não cairia no elseif abaixo
                // então explicitamente tenta executar de novo
                continue;
            }
            else if ( one && Vars.BeepEnable )
            {
                Console.Beep( 3000 , 200 );
                one = !one;
            }
            // Se chegou aqui, não tinha dados a processar.
            // Dar uma folga a espera de novos dados.
            System.Threading.Thread.Yield();
        }
```

### Observação

- Esse número 24 parece meio mágico. Ver se é exigência da API que está usando. Mas se for só uma tentativa de balancear carga entre rodadas e beeps, o melhor seria tirar esse `for`, e mover o teste do beep para dentro do while.

Comment: Parece interessante o uso de `System.Threading.Thread.Yield`.

Answer (score -1):

Diminua a quantidade de If´s em seu programa, pelo que vi você pode utilizar um and em alguns if's, isso deve melhorar um pouco.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, acredito que isso vá melhorar um pouco, mas não o bastante, já que o fato do programa sobrecarregar muito é por ele estar dentro de um `while true`.